# Cutom Url for WordPress page breaks

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress for my blog. Because of very big articles I'm using Page Brakes to split them in multiple pages. Right now the default url for these articles are like this:

```
Main Page: http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title
```

*After using Page Break:*

```
Second Page - http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title/2/

Third Page - http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title/3/
```

---

**I want to show text in place of these numbers. For example**

```
Second Page - http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title/2/
```

**will become**

```
Second Page - http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title/second-page/
```

*or*

```
Second Page - http://www.mywesite.com/some-article-title/design-ideas/
```

Is it possible to do that in WordPress? How to do that?

Comment: I think your looking for these => https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-permalink-sturucture-breaks-page-urls. there are lots of free plugin available to make custom url to pagebreak eg => https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-break/ else simply you can do it by htaccess.

Comment: I think these both links doesn't provide what I am looking for. Can you explain this to me?